# .NET MVC -- Using Composition in a View Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewmodel, composition

I am trying to wrap my head around the idea of Composition.  Never used it before.  I have a class that looks like this (thinned down):

```
    public class AccountProfile
    {
        public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public void GetAccountProfile()
        {
            AccountNumber = "123456";  // eventual these will become values from the database
            FirstName = "John";
            LastName = "Smith";
        }
    }
```

Then, in my view model, I'd like to have access to AccountNumber, FirstName, and LastName.  I don't want to use inheritance, as this view model will need access to multiple external, unrelated classes. So far the model is simple:

```
public class AccountProfileViewModel
{
    public AccountProfileViewModel() { }
}
```

Here's what I've tried so far, none which are correct:

```
public class AccountProfileViewModel
{
    AP= new AccountProfile();
    public AccountProfileViewModel() { }
}
```

That one (above) throws multiple errors and won't compile.  I've also tried this:

```
public class AccountProfileViewModel
{
    public AccountProfile AP { get; set; }
    public AccountProfileViewModel() { }
}
```

This one (the one above) compiles just fine, but it throws a run-time error in the controller when I try and use it:

```
    model.AP.GetAccountProfile();
```

The error: {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}

I'm out of ideas.  Thanks!

Comment: so do you just want to reference AccountProfile the the ViewModel?

Comment: Yes.  And in the controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to initialize the object at least.

```
public class AccountProfileViewModel
{
    public AccountProfile AP { get; set; }

    public AccountProfileViewModel() { 
        AP = new AccountProfile();
    }
}
```

Comment: That was it!  Thanks.  I'll mark as the answer when I can.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are trying to achieve is something like this:

```
public class AccountProfileViewModel
{
    public AccountProfile AP { get; set; }

    public AccountProfileViewModel() { }
}
```

or if `AccountProfileViewModel` really needs `AccountProfile` you can do

```
public class AccountProfileViewModel
{
    public AccountProfile AP { get; set; }

    public AccountProfileViewModel(AccountProfile profile) {
         this.AP = profile;
    }
}
```

and in your controller you can do something like this

```
public class controller {
     public ActionResult Index(){
      var vm = new AccountProfileViewModel();
      var ap = //Get accountProfile
      vm.AP = ap;
      return View(vm);
    }
}
```

or in the case of example where you need the `AccountProfile`

```
public class controller {
     public ActionResult Index(){
      var ap = //Get accountProfile
      var vm = new AccountProfileViewModel(ap);
      return View(vm);
    }
}
```

you want `AccountProfileViewModel` to have an instance of the `AccountProfile` but you want to set it in the controller.

then in your view you can do `Model.AP.AccountNumber` for instance

Answer (score 0):

If you need an object reference in this class then it's my personal preference to only create the object if it's required like so:

```
public class AccountProfileViewModel
{
    private AccountProfile _ap;

    public AccountProfile AP 
    { 
        get { return _ap ?? (_ap = new AccountProfile()); }
        set { _ap = value; }
    }
}
```

If you actually use `yourObject.AP` then it will have a reference created / return the existing one but if it's not used then no reference has been created.